# Method in child class not called (properly)

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class "**FileButton**". It's purpose is to link a file to a JButton, **FileButton** inherits from **JButton**. Child classes inherit from this to do usefull stuff with the file linked to the button.

The Class **JingleCardButton** is one of those child classes. This Child Class has a method that can play the jingle linked to the **JingleCardButton** when the button is clicked with the method "*playSound()*". This method isn't available in other child classes that inherit from **FileButton**

Also, i have a class **Card** that maintains a grid of **FileButton** objects on a specified JPanel. The Class **JingleCard** inherits from **Card** and maintains **JingleCardButton** objects.

Since every kind of **Card** needs to store all of its, the 2D buttonGrid array is declared in the base class **Card**.

```
   protected FileButton[][] buttonGrid; //the 2d area containing all FileButton objects is declared in "Card".
```

This is the constructor in **JingleCard**

```
  public JingleCard(JPanel p, int xdim, int ydim, JToggleButton editButton) {
        super(p,xdim,ydim,editButton); // calling the constructor in Card
        buttonGrid= new JingleCardButton[xdim][ydim];
        for (int row= 0; row< xdim; row++) {
          for (int column= 0; column< ydim; column++) {
            buttonGrid[row][column] = new JingleCardButton(null);
            buttonGrid[row][column].addActionListener(this);
            p.add(buttonGrid[row][column]);
        }

        p.doLayout();
    }        
            p.doLayout();
        }
    }
```

Now i have a JingleCard, a 2D array filled with JingleCardButtons. After adding the mp3 file to the button (there's no file linked automatically when creating a card) with the GUI.

Now i should be able (i think so) to play the jingle assigned with the gui to a **JingleCardButton** somewhere in the **JingleCard's** *ButtonGrid*.

```
buttonGrid[row][column].playSound(); //syntax to play the sound is just like here: instance_of_JingleCardButton.playSound();
```

I have no idea why, but when compiling this in Netbeans, this produces an error...  According to Netbeans, the method *PlaySound()* can't be found in the class **FileButton**. (that's true, because it's in the child class **JingleCardButton**).

What's causing this problem? I'm sure that **buttonGrid** contains **JingleCardButton** objects, and calling *playSound()* should work. I don't see what's going wrong.

(some of the classes mentioned also implements ActionListener en Serializable)

Comment: For one, your classes shouldn't be extending JButton, but rather you will want to extend from AbstractAction, and then set each button's Action with your subclass.

Comment: The button's "action", what it does when pressed, is not part of the JButton itself, but of its ActionListener or better, its Action, and this is why I strongly urge you to make this fundamental change.

Comment: You said in your code that you are calling FileButton objects...
"protected FileButton[][] buttonGrid"
You need to change it or just cast it when you are calling method PlaySound(). Simply Try this: ((JingleCardButton)buttonGrid[row][collumn]).playSound();

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: thank for the great tip. I'll keep that in mind for the future. I learned something new today.

Comment: @nosbor thanks for the simple solution. I think I confused some principles of inheritance.

Comment: The buttonGrid is indeed declared in the base class. I thought that it automatically will be casted to JingleCardButton when declaring it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttonGrid is an array of FileButton, and so the compiler sees each item in the array as being of FileButton type. Now even if you fill the array with JingleCardButton objects, the Java compiler will only allow you to call FileButton methods on the items in the array. You can sort of understand the rationale by thinking that since Java has no way of knowing that later you might not switch out an item in the array with a FileButton object of different sub-type, it has to err on the side of safety and limit what you can do with that variable.

One possible solution is to check the type object held by the variable using the instanceof operator, and then casting the variable to that of JingleCardButton

```
if (buttonGrid[row][column] instanceof JingleCardButton) {
    ((JingleCardButton) buttonGrid[row][column]).playSound();
}
```

... but that results in dirty code, code that is brittle and easily broken.

Better is to not even sub-type JButton since you don't appear to be wanting to change the innate properties of a JButton, but rather its behaviors when pressed. This behavior is not dictated by the button itself but rather by what Action it is set to, or what ActionListeners have been added to it. For this reason I strongly encourage you to create classes that extend AbstractAction and not JButton, not unless there are other JButton behaviors, behaviors that are unrelated to its action listener behavior, that you wish to modify.